# F-15 APU or JFS

Tags: apu, f-15

Can a portable GTCP-85 series be used on an F-15? Or is there no capability to use an external APU. As I understand, F-15's use the JFS-190?

Comment: You have two questions here that should be separated in two posts.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my format style, it's been adjusted. Now can you provide any insight to the question? This should be interesting.

Comment: Any jet fighter aircraft can use an external APU that provides the appropriate voltage and amperage. Generally an APU is defined as a device that provides electrical power, and in some cases (such as the APU on a CH-46 helicopter) also hydraulic power. The JFS-190 is different in that it is intended to help start the engines. It provides hydraulic power and *mechanical* power to start the engines using clutch plates.

Comment: I believe I have found the answer. F-15's use Generator Set, Gas Turbine Engine Model A/M32A-60A nsn 6115-00-420-8486. FInally someone on flight line was able to assist. But thanks for your help amigo!

Comment: Cool beans, glad you found what you wanted. 